# Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I restored a backup of a database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012.

When I try to access a particular page of my application, I get this error:

> Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist

It works with my 2008 R2 project perfectly. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The solution that worked for me was `ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON DATABASE::[<dbname>] TO [sa];` as noted on the question that is stated above as the original of this duplicate.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You need to give the database a valid owner. Use the [`ALTER AUTHORIZATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359(v=sql.105).aspx) command to do this:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION 
ON DATABASE::[DatabaseName]
TO [A Suitable Login];
```

[Related Knowledge Base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913423)

Note the [sp_changedbowner](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178630(v=sql.105).aspx) system stored procedure has been deprecated in favour of `ALTER AUTHORIZATION`.